# Firebase displayName error

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am getting this error

> Authentication failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName'
>   of undefined.

along with that,it shows that my fbRef is undefined.
I don't know the reason. I am new to Angular and firebase so I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this.

my index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
   <title></title>
   <!-- bower:css -->
   <!-- endbower -->
   <!-- compiled css output -->
   <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tab-chat.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tab-dash.css">

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.4/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
 <script>
   Initialize Firebase
   var config = {
     apiKey: "AIzaSyDPCScioFS49tW0rPCjQliUKh5j0Rcw72M",
     authDomain: "skinder-858b9.firebaseapp.com",
     databaseURL: "https://skinder-858b9.firebaseio.com",
     storageBucket: "skinder-858b9.appspot.com",
     messagingSenderId: "280323404236"
      };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
 </script>





<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ng-cordova-oauth/ng-cordova-oauth.js"></script>
<!--rsvp liv-->
<script src="lib/rsvp/rsvp.js"></script>
<!---->

<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="lib/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angularfire/dist/angularfire.js"></script>
<script src="lib/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
<script src="lib/geofire/dist/geofire.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-elastic/elastic.js"></script>
<script src="lib/rxjs/dist/rx.lite.compat.js"></script> </head>
<script src="lib/angular-audio/app/angular.audio.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angular-rx/dist/rx.angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/parse-js-sdk/lib/parse.js"></script>
<!-- -->
<script src="lib/angular-rx/dist/rx.angular.map"></script>
<!-- endbower -->

  <!-- inject:js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/chat/chat_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/chat/message_service.js"></script>
<script src="js/chat_post/post_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/chat_post/posts_service.js"></script>
<script src="js/dash_page/dash_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/dash_page/get_user_service.js"></script>
<script src="js/login/login_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/logout/logout_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/map/map_controller.js"></script>
<script src="js/main/main_controller.js"></script>

<!-- endinject -->
  <!--for testing-->
  <!--todo remove in production-->
  <script src="js/services/state-watcher.service.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="skinder">
 <!--
  The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
-->
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
   <ion-nav-back-button>
   </ion-nav-back-button>
 </ion-nav-bar>
<!--
  The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
  Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
  have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
-->
   <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
 </body>
</html>
```

my login controller is

```
/*global Firebase*/
 (function(angular) {
 'use strict';
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDPCScioFS49tW0rPCjQliUKh5j0Rcw72M",
    authDomain: "skinder-858b9.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://skinder-858b9.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "skinder-858b9.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "280323404236"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    angular.module('skinder')
    .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase',   '$firebaseAuth','$firebaseObject', '$window', '$rootScope', '$state',  LoginCtrl]);
    function LoginCtrl($scope, $firebase, $firebaseAuth,$firebaseObject, $window, $rootScope, $state) {

  $scope.login = function () {
    var userKey = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    var fbRef = firebase.database().ref();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
      .then(function(authData) {
        console.log("Logged in as:", authData);
        $rootScope.userKey = authData.uid;  
        $state.go('tab.dash');
        console.log("value of fbRef is :",fbRef);
        console.log("value of userKey is:",userKey);

        //todo refactor this to service
        //add new user ref to fireabase
        fbRef.child('users/'+authData.uid).set({
          provider: authData.provider,
          user_name: authData.facebook.displayName,
          picture: authData.facebook.photoURL
        });
        return authData;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
      });
  };

  //$scope.simpleLogin = $firebaseSimpleLogin(fbRef);
  //$scope.errors = [];
  //$scope.user = {
  //  email: '',
  //  password: ''
  //};
  //
  //$scope.login = function() {
  //  $scope.errors = [];
  //
  //  if ($scope.user.email === '') {
  //    $scope.errors.push('Please enter your email');
  //  }
  //
  //  if ($scope.user.password === '') {
  //    $scope.errors.push('Please enter your password');
  //  }
  //
  //  if ($scope.errors.length > 0) {
  //    return;
  //  }
  //
  //  var promise = $scope.simpleLogin.$login('password', {
  //    email: $scope.user.email,
  //    password: $scope.user.password
  //  });
  //
  //  promise.then(function(user) {
  //    console.log(user);
  //    $rootScope.user = user;
  //    $window.location.href = '/#/main';
  //  }, function(error) {
  //    console.error(error);
  //    if (error.code === 'INVALID_EMAIL') {
  //      $scope.errors.push('The email was invalid');
  //    }
  //    if (error.code === 'INVALID_PASSWORD') {
  //      $scope.errors.push('The password was invalid');
  //    }
  //  });
  //
  //};

}

}(window.angular));
```

I would really appreciate any help on this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Since this is the only place you use displayName: `authData.facebook.displayName`, it seems that the user is not signed in with Facebook.

Comment: signInWithPopup does not resolve with a result that contains the properties you are using. The result contains a user property and that contains the providerData array which contains the facebook display name: result.user.providerData[0].displayName.

Comment: try this first - you must get the user object returned from a succesful login; var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

if (user != null) {
  user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
    console.log("Sign-in provider: "+profile.providerId);
    console.log("  Provider-specific UID: "+profile.uid);
    console.log("  Name: "+profile.displayName);
    console.log("  Email: "+profile.email);
    console.log("  Photo URL: "+profile.photoURL);
  });
}

Comment: @SunilKumar I am getting the user object successfully after checking with the code above.  I guess it's got to do with the JSON?

Comment: what do you get as output for this [console.log("Logged in as:", authData);] ?

Comment: @SunilKumar I get the access token ,provider, displayName, username and the other parameters as the output.

Comment: what do you get if you console.log("Logged in as:", authData);; console.log(authData.facebook.displayName);console.log("Provider:", authData.provider);

Comment: @SunilKumar the issue is resolved, It was the "facebook" in the "facebook.displayName" that was causing the error. Really grateful for your help! Thank you!

Comment: Please post your fix as an Answer, that would help other followers of this post